# Subtract months from given date

Tags: perl, date, unix, ksh

I have a date in the future, from which I have to subtract 3 months at a time until the current date is reached.

- The reached date after subtracting the months must be closest to the current date, but has to be in the future.
- The day of the month is always the 23rd

i.e.:

- future date = 2015/01/23
- current date = 2014/06/05
- result = 2014/07/23

I'm running Solaris, so don't have access to GNU date.

I tried to do this in Perl, but unfortunately I can only use the `Time::Local` module:

```
#!/bin/ksh

m_date="2019/05/23"
m_year=$(echo $m_date|cut -d/ -f1)
m_month=$(echo $m_date|cut -d/ -f2)
m_day=$(echo $m_date|cut -d/ -f3)
export m_year m_month m_day

perl -MTime::Local -le '
  $time = timelocal(localtime);
  $i = 3;
  while (timelocal(0, 0, 0, $ENV{'m_day'}, $ENV{'m_month'} - $i, $ENV{'m_year'}) > $time) {
    print scalar(localtime(timelocal(0, 0, 0, $ENV{'m_day'}, $ENV{'m_month'} - $i, $ENV{'m_year'})));
    $i += 3;
  }
'
```

This only works for months within one year. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: "I tried to do this in Perl, but unfortunately I can only use the Time::Local module" - I strongly suspect that's not true. But, if it is, that should be the first problem that you should solve. If you're not using a relatively recent version of Perl with access to CPAN modules, then you're not programming in Perl :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple enough to just split the date strings and do the arithmetic on the fields.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $future = '2015/01/23';
my $current = do {
  my @current = localtime;
  $current[3] += 1;
  $current[5] += 1900;
  sprintf '%04d/%02d/%02d', @current[5,4,3];
};
my $result;

for (my $test = $future; $test gt $current; ) {
  $result = $test;
  my @test = split /\//, $test;
  if (($test[1] -= 3) < 1) {
    --$test[0];
    $test[1] += 12;
  }
  $test = sprintf '%04d/%02d/%02d', @test;
}

say $result;
```

**output**

```
2014/07/23
```

Alternatively you could just do the division to calculate how many whole quarters to subtract, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $future = '2015/01/23';

my @current = (localtime)[5,4,3];
$current[1] += 1;
$current[0] += 1900;

my @future  = split /\//, $future;

my $months = ($future[0] - $current[0]) * 12 + $future[1] - $current[1];
$months -= 1 if $current[2] >= 23;

my @result = @current;
$result[2] = 23;
$result[1] += $months % 3;
$result[0] += int(($result[1] - 1) / 12);
$result[1] = ($result[1] - 1) % 12 + 1;
my $result = sprintf '%04d/%02d/%02d', @result;

say $result;
```

The output is identical to that of the previous code

Comment: unfortunately not, I'm running version 5.8. It seems that Time::Piece works only works with >5.10

Comment: Version 8 of Perl 5 was released twelve years ago: you really should do something about that. In particular version 10 has a significant number of improvements.

Answer (score 1):

This is your script changed so it should work across multiple years,

```
perl -MTime::Local -le'
  sub nextm {
    $ENV{m_year}--, $ENV{m_month} +=12 if ($ENV{m_month} -= 3) <1;
    timelocal(0, 0, 0, $ENV{m_day}, $ENV{m_month}, $ENV{m_year});
  }
  my $time = timelocal(localtime);
  while ((my $c=nextm()) > $time) {
    print scalar localtime($c);
  }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# just convert the real date that you have to epoch
my $torig = 1558569600; 
my $tnow = time;
# 3 months in seconds to use the epoch everywhere
my $estep = 3 * 30 * 24 * 3600;
while(($torig - $estep) > $tnow){
  $torig -= $estep;
}
print $torig,"\n";
print scalar localtime($torig),"\n";
```

The only problem here is that a months is an approximation, if you need the very same day but minus 3 months, you could use DateCalc

Answer (score 0):

I ended up scripting it all in KSH instead of perl, thanks to Borodin's logic.

```
#!/bin/ksh

set -A c_date $(date '+%Y %m %d')

IFS=/ d="2019/05/23"
set -A m_date $d

[[ ${c_date[2]} -gt ${m_date[2]} ]] && ((c_date[1]+=1))
c_date[2]=${m_date[2]}

c_date[1]=$(( (((${m_date[0]} - ${c_date[0]}) * 12) + (${m_date[1]} - ${c_date[1]})) % 3 + ${c_date[1]} ))

if [[ ${c_date[1]} -gt 12 ]] ; then
        ((c_date[0]+=1))
        ((c_date[1]-=12))
fi

echo ${c_date[@]}
```